# Is there a way to get email or text notifications each time data is written to my Google Cloud Firestore bucket?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, twilio

I have a google cloud bucket and firebase writes my app data there. I would like to monitor my data, and have any new update (write) to my firebase database it sent via a text or email to me. I currently have Twilio set up on Nodejs to send texts on Firebase and my code is:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var twilio = require('twilio');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
var accountSid = 'account id'; // Account SID from www.twilio.com/console
var authToken = 'account token';   // Auth Token from www.twilio.com/console

var client = new twilio(accountSid, authToken);

exports.useWildcard = functions.firestore
    .document('comments/{commentContent}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
      client.messages.create({
    body: context.params.commentContent,
    to: '+15555555555',  // Text this number
    from: '+15555555556' // From a valid Twilio number
    })
    .then((message) => console.log(message.sid));
    });
```

Currently, I would like to build it out for just the comments document, which are organized inside firebase through `comments/{commentContent}`. Later, I would like to expand to other trees. I am however, unsure if the above will run each time there is a write to my comments tree. Does it require the `firebase-admin` module as I have put above? Thanks!

Comment: I think function triggered by storage seems to be only choice, especially that you have to detect somehow if data is indeed "offensive material". How do you plan to achieve this?

Comment: Thanks, my current approach is to try to get a text message for each new write to my database, and to do removal manually. I have updated the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `onWrite` method will not only run when there is a write to the comments tree, but will also be triggered by any change in any document and on the deletion of a document. This means that right now your code will responde in the same way to any of the above cases, and this could cause problems, especially in the case of a document being deleted since it will try to send a comment that doesent exist and will likely get some null exceptions.

Said that you have different solutions.
If you only want the function to react to a new comment, but not to an update or deletion you should use `onCreate` trigger instead of `onWrite`.

If you also want to handle a comment update notification you can use both `onCreate` and `onUpdate`, but sending different messages by doing something like:

```
exports.useWildcardCreate = functions.firestore
    .document('comments/{commentContent}')
    .onCreate((change, context) => {
      client.messages.create({
    body: context.params.commentContent,
    to: '+15555555555',  // Text this number
    from: '+15555555556' // From a valid Twilio number
    })
    .then((message) => console.log(message.sid));
    });

exports.useWildcardUpdate = functions.firestore
    .document('comments/{commentContent}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {

        const newComment = change.after.data();
        const previuosComment = change.before.data();

      client.messages.create({
    body: 'The comment ${previuosComment} has been changed to  ${newComment}',
    to: '+15555555555',  // Text this number
    from: '+15555555556' // From a valid Twilio number
    })
    .then((message) => console.log(message.sid));
    });
```

At last if you also need to notify when a comment has been deleted you should use `onWrite` method but differentiating between the 3 different cases as shown below:

```
exports.useWildcard = functions.firestore
    .document('comments/{commentContent}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
    var textBody;
    const oldComment = change.before.data();
    const newComment = change.after.data();

    if (change.after.exists == false) { // comment has been deleted
        textBody = 'The comment ${oldComment} has been deleted';
    }
    else if (oldComment != newComment) { // comment has been updated
        textBody = 'The comment ${oldComment} has been changed to ${newComment}';
    }
    else { // if its not an update or a deletion its a new comment
        textBody = newComment;
    }
      client.messages.create({
    body: textBody,
    to: '+15555555555',  // Text this number
    from: '+15555555556' // From a valid Twilio number
    })
    .then((message) => console.log(message.sid));
    });
```

Finally `require('firebase-admin')` is needed since it will allow you to interact with Firebase from privileged environments. Here you can find all the information to the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)